# IE6 Bug in Smooth DIV Scroll

Tags: html, scroll, cross-browser, internet-explorer-6, smoothing

I'm using [Smooth DIV Scroll](http://www.smoothdivscroll.com/) for a project.
Anyone knows how to make it work in **IE6**?

I've seen it done but am not sure how.

Comment: What isn't working and what have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

You don't mention anything about what is not working?

I don't have a real computer where Internet Explorer 6 is installed, but I do have a virtual machine running Windows XP (SP3) and IE 6. This should be the same as the real thing. On this machine I can run Smooth Div Scroll in IE6 without any bigger problems.

There is one issue with the height of the hotspots - for some reason setting the height of the hotspots to 100% will not work in IE 6 (go figure). So if you plan on using the hotspots for scrolling and you know the height of your scroller, you can set a pixel value and it will work.

In the file smoothDivScroll.css or in your page CSS try the following:

```
div.scrollingHotSpotLeft, div.scrollingHotSpotRight 
{
   height: 250px;
}
```

...if the height of all your scrollers are 250px. This will fix the issue with the short hotspots when using IE 6. If you ask me, I'm amazed Smooth Div Scroll works at all in IE 6.